# GCM 3.0 - send notification paylod to iOS and data payload to Android?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

I would like to use the notification payload for iOS notifications (not Android), and the data payload for Android.

Is this possible? I am worried by using the notification payload for iOS, the Android notification will ben generated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a single `topic`, if you want to deliver a push via `notification` payload on iOS, but via `data` payload on Android, you can't!

For example, if you have a `topic` called `"awesome_news"` you should split this into two topics:  `"awesome_news_ios"` and `"awesome_news_android"`